# Read binary data from serial port and save in file

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, serial, modem

I am link modem to pi3 via serial port and configure this port .
When i receive data in my python software from serial port and save bytes in file, i note i receive too mutch data ,
I am receiving byte by byte ,
For example if transmited data  from modem to pi3  was 1.5 kbyte , my softwre receive 5.5 k byte.

I note there is many line duplicated .

I use
port. Read()
Shul i use read until or read inwait?
Can any one help me or explain this matter?

Comment: Not a Pi specific question.  Wherever you ask this question you will need to show the code you used and an example of the output against the expected output.

Comment: are you certain that baud rates, bit settings are correct?  One can usually expect some noise too that should be rejected by checking parity or some additional embedded check.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import serial
                b = open("/home/pi/20", "wb")
                byte=port.read()
                num_byte+=1
                while True:
                       if byte== b'\x10':
                            x = port.read(1)
                            if x== b'\x03':
                                #b.write(b'\x10x\03')
                                print('end of file')
                                num_byte+=2
                                b.close()
                                break
                            
                            if x == b'\x10':
                                b.write(b'\x10')
                                byte = port.read(1)
                                num_byte+=1
                                continue
                            if x== b'\x1a':
                                b.write(b'\x10\x10')
                                num_byte+=2
                                byte = port.read(1)
                                continue
                            else:
                                
                               
                                byte = port.read(1)
                                num_byte+=2
                                continue
```